# How to get list of Pojos from collection of map

Tags: java, java-8

```
Collection<Map<String, MyObj>>
```

I need to collect list of MyObj from above structure. 
For instance I also had `Collection<MyObj>` - in this for collecting list of MyObj I did below

```
List<MyObj> result = new ArrayList<>(MyObj);
```

works fine.

How do I achieve similar result from `Collection<Map<String, MyObj>>`?

Comment: Asiide - `new ArrayList<>(MyObj)` might have been `new ArrayList<MyObj>()` whcih can just be left as `new ArrayList<>()`

Comment: @Naman I think the second `MyObj` is supposed to represent some `List<MyObj>`.

Answer (score 4):

So you want to flatten the maps to a single list of values? You can use streams to do this pretty easily:

```
List<MyObj> list = collection.stream()
        .map(Map::values)
        .flatMap(Collection::stream)
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do:

```
List<MyObj> result = collections.stream()
            .flatMap(m->m.values().stream())
            .collect(toList());
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

- Takes the map values and streams them and collects them into a list.

```
List<MyObj> obList = origList.stream()
            .flatMap(m->m.values().stream())
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
```